# restart service crontab problem

Tags: linux, bash, cron

if i run the script below manually from putty (as root) then the service is restarted no problem

### manual command

```
sh /home/auser/server/reService.sh >> /var/log/reService.log
```

But if the same script is scheduled as a cronjob, also under root:

### crontab command

```
00 07 * * * /home/auser/server/reService.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/reService.log
```

then the 'service myService restart' is not executed successfully: service is not restarted, and no command output in scheduled log compared to manual log. I can also tell you that nothing after the restart line executes if scheduled.

Why, am I missing some privileges when going through crontab? How can i successfully schedule restarting of myService?

thanks ahead.

### reService.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "============================================================================="
echo "Daily restarting of my service"
date
echo "============================================================================="
service myService restart
exit 0
```

### manual log

```
 [H [J=============================================================================
Daily restarting of my service
Thu May 19 04:51:12 EDT 2011
=============================================================================
Stopping myService   ..done
Starting myService   ..done
```

### scheduled log

```
=============================================================================
Daily restarting of my service
Thu May 19 07:00:02 EDT 2011
=============================================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The use of `sh` in your manual example implies that the script doesn't have execute permission.  Try setting that or calling sh in the same way within the crontab (I prefer the former).</strike>

**EDIT**: OK, it's not permissions.  Next thing to look at is $PATH; echo that to the log file and compare them.

**EDIT2**: If PATH is the issue, then just set it within crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/‌​openwin/bin:/usr/java/bin:/root/bin 

00 07 * * * /home/auser/server/reService.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/reService.log
```

Comment: also, it's incorrect calling it via `sh` because it's a bash script (or so says the `#!/bin/bash`, although all code inside is POSIX compliant)

Comment: hmm Thinking it better, I don't think it's a permission issue, as the `echo`s are getting executed

Comment: if the script wasn't executing at all, it shouldn't put some traces in the /var/log/reService.log, thus it seems to have the logs till it restart the service...

Comment: 1) owner, group and others have x permission on reService.sh

Comment: 2) i tried scheduling in crontab with sh in front, but that did not help

Comment: 3) running manually without sh in front did not make a difference: manual still works

Comment: 4) in the original post i said any commands after service... would not run, but i was wrong: only the service myService restart does not appear in the scheduled log, other commands do

Comment: so i think access overall is ok, but there is some specific problem with executing the service command ? what else could i try?

Comment: PATH seems very promising!:
    Manual path is /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/java/bin:/root/bin
    Scheduled path is /usr/bin:/bin
I'm afraid I don't know how to make the scheduled path the same as the manual/putty path?

Comment: the scheduled service command executes now !! for some reason, the service is stopped when scheduled, but when scheduled the service is not started up again successfully? but i think that is to do with some specific requirement of the specific service im working with because i tried the scheduled restart with sendmail service and sendmail was successfully started up .. thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem and adding the `PATH=...` line helped. But Isn't adding so many paths to your crontab a **security issue?** Can't I just add the correct path to the one line on crontab?