# Calling to restart a "service" in Linux from Python script not working from within crontab entry

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have the following python test script (extracted from a much bigger .py file) which I'm trying to get working on an EC2 instance (haproxy OpsWorks instance).

There seems to be a major difference between the permissions applied when running as a cron entry versus running as a python script from the shell.

The closest I've found in any other posts is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124699/restart-service-crontab-problem) but that's relating to shell scripts and, given that I'm running python OK, the paths should ( I hope ) be sufficiently configured for the cronjob.

Environment:
  - Python version: 2.6.8
  - Environment: OpsWorks HAProxy instance, on EC2.
  - Running as user: root.

Script

```
import subprocess
import boto
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(boto.logging.INFO)
    command = ['service', 'haproxy', 'reload'];
    logging.info('Executing: %s' % command)
    #shell=FALSE for sudo to work.
    subprocess.call(command, shell=False)
```

I have alternatively tried calling the subprocess command using the following to no avail.

```
# subprocess.call("%s %s %s %s" % ('sudo', 'service', 'haproxy', 'reload'))
```

Output when run from the command line:

```
[root@lb1 ~]# python tester.py
INFO:root:Executing: ['service', 'haproxy', 'reload']
Reloading haproxy:
[root@lb1 ~]#
```

Crontab entry:

```
[root@lb1 ~]# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * python ~/tester.py > ~/testlog 2>&1
```

Output when run as a crontab command

```
[root@lb1 ~]# cat testlog
INFO:root:Executing: ['service', 'haproxy', 'reload']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/tester.py", line 13, in <module>
    subprocess.call(command, shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm confused as to why on earth it's throwing the "No Such File Or Directory" error!

Can anyone provide any pointers?  Incidentally this is part of a much bigger EC2 integration piece - hence the boto import [it's a nice way to get logging in this instance].  It's running as root because, from browsing SO, it's bad practice to have a cron entry for a user account running with a sudo command.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is indeed path related.

[Path Information for Cronjobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user) 
[Commands in submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250365/crontab-fails-to-execute-python-script)

To solve it I provided the following entries via `crontab -e`

```
[root@lb1 ~]# crontab -l
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Now my service restarts as expected. Yay!

Answer (score 4):

In subprocess set `shell=True`

```
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

I think your problem will be solved but sudo problem may be arised.